# UI automation code for Optimizely test

Tags: java, automation, optimizely

I am new to Optimizely A/B testing. My question is, I have automation code of test cases for UI and if someone changes the UI using Optimizely, How can I make sure my automation code of test cases doesn't break because of those new changes from Optimizely ??

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't; Optimizely is code injection. It's the responsibility of whoever's monkey-patching the UI not to break it.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got something like Selenium or Ghost Inspector checking things on an actual running website using URL's as a target, you can just opt-out of Optimizely tests for the purposes of verifying your UI. To do that add `optimizely_disable=true` or `optimizely_opt_out=true` as a query parameter to the URL's you're checking. i.e. http://youramazingsite.com?optimizely_disable=true